# total memory used by running python code

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I am running python program using Linux operating system and i want to know how much total memory used for this process. Is there any way to determine the total memory usage  ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164653/actual-memory-usage-of-a-process ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a python way to do it:

```
import os

# obtain the current process id
pid = str(os.getpid())

# read the process system status
status = os.system('cat /proc/' + pid + '/status')

print status
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use psutil module. 
It can be installed with `sudo pip install psutil`

```
import os, psutil
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print process.memory_info().rss
```

This is crossplaform method.

Answer (score 0):

You can just open task manager and look how much ram does it take. I use Ubuntu and it came preinstalled.